# Building libsndfile in Fedora with Ogg Flac and Vorbis

Tags: linux, fedora, libsndfile

I'm trying to build the libsndfile library in Fedora 20 with the added options of Flac, Ogg and Vorbis.

So, as the readme says I installed flac ogg and vorbis using this command:

```
sudo yum install flac libogg libvorbis
```

After that I did the ./configure in libsndfile source like the readme says but when it does that it says it can't find flac, vorbis and vorbisenc (it DID find ogg). This is the output from the ./configure command:

```
checking for flac >= 1.2.1 ... no
checking for ogg >= 1.1.3 ... yes
checking for vorbis >= 1.2.3 ... no
checking for vorbisenc >= 1.2.3 ... no
```

I checked the versions of flac and the vorbis install and they both are higher than the minimum requested version.

How can I make the ./configure file find those libraries so I can build libsndfile like I want?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many distributions, a package, like `libogg`, contains only the shared (and maybe static) libraries for the package - whatever is required to run other programs that are already linked with that library. The C header files and other support files that are needed for actually building a new application that uses that library are generally not included in this package, but in another one, often named with a `-devel` or `-dev` suffix - `libogg-devel` in this case. So what you need to do in order to build the package you are trying to build in this case, based on the given output, would be:

```
yum install flac-devel libogg-devel libvorbis-devel vorbis-tools
```

The `vorbis-tools` package doesn't fit the above description, but it is where the `vorbisenc` binary mentioned in the output is packaged...